# Files written in Ubuntu disappear in Windows

Tags: dual-boot, ntfs

I have a strange problem with a dual boot laptop, in where I have a ntfs partition.

When I write files in the ntfs patitions everything seems fine. even if I restart Ubuntu the files still are there, but when I boot in windows and access the disk the data disapears, and desapears in both systems.

In windows I have full permitions, but in ubuntu root is the owner of that filesystem.

Comment: I would try sync or sudo sync before rebooting.  specifically moreso if you sudo init 6 instead of menu reboot

Answer (score 5):

One way to cause this problem is to hibernate your Windows and then use Ubuntu to write files to the NTFS partition. The Windows hibernation file then becomes asynchronous with the new data on the NTFS partition.

One way to loosely verify the this particular problem is just to experiment with it.

Or,  use data recovery software on the NTFS partition without booting into Windows. (That is to say: boot into Windows; hibernate Windows; boot into Ubuntu; write some files to NTFS; shutdown; remove laptop disk, plug laptop disk into another computer via USB, and then use recovery software.) The software will pick up files that may or may not be connected with the master file table (MFT). Then you can see that files are in fact written to the NTFS partition, but Windows does not "see" them after restoring the state of the system at hibernation time.

Also, a `chkdsk` from Windows on the NTFS partition might reveal problems.

And, aking1012 mentioned sync, which you can do with `sudo sync` before rebooting to assure yourself that all file system data was flushed to disk for troubleshooting purposes.

Was this the source of the problem? Success?

Comment: Not really, it seems like windows is deleting the files, however the disk utilization, actually shows that there space used.

Answer (score 3):

All my photos was on a third partition, and I thought I'll newer see them again.
The Windows was in hibernate mode, and I wrote with Ubuntu on it.
From Windows command line wasn't possible to run the chkdsk command as a supervisor.

But

1. Open the "Computer" window
2. Right-click on the drive in question
3. Select Properties than the "Tools" tab
4. In the Error-checking area, click

The drive was unmounted, and my data was back.